# Why should StringBuilder implement CharSequence if it inherits it from AbstractStringBuilder anyway?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, stringbuilder

The class `StringBuilder extends AbstractStringBuilder` and `implements java.io.Serializable, CharSequence`.

And `AbstractStringBuilder implements Appendable, CharSequence`.

Both classes are since 1.5. Can anybody explain why `StringBuilder` should implement `CharSequence` but not `Appendable`? It inherits both of them from `AbstractStringBuilder` anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantically it is exactly the same whether `implements CharSequence` is specified or not. Why `StringBuilder` has this explicitly declared cannot be answered except by reviewing the history of the JDK's codebase, and anyway the answer wouldn't be very informative.

For example, the abstract superclass may have been introduced later, where the earlier version of `StringBuilder` did need that `implements` clause. After introducing the abstract class, this could have been removed, but wasn't, with no harm done.

Comment: Interestingly, the `AbstractStringBuilder` isn't in the JavaDoc (5, 6 and 7, cf. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which might imply that somebody figured other classes might benefit from extending this - but that was abandoned or never needed...

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup That's a very good point indeed. I've never noticed such a phenomenon that the Javadoc is in effect lying about the superclass, but since `AbstractStringBuilder` is package-private, maybe this is in fact the norm. The docs document explicitly that `StringBuilder` implements `Appendable`, though.